# What are "bodyLength" and "checkSum" in QuickFix?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

Anyone here can tell me what are "bodyLength" and "checkSum" in QuickFix?

I have searched on [this](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/namespace_f_i_x_1_1_f_i_e_l_d.html#aac36b44ae2683cdf53dd263b82e735d1) and there is no definition.

What is the purpose of those in Message (tag = 9 and 10)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your question is about **FIX, which is a protocol**, not QuickFIX, which is just an engine that can be used for FIX programs.

Second, if you are going to work with FIX (and, given your many recent SO questions, you obviously are), then **you really need to acquaint yourself with the FIX specifications**.

You can create an account for free at http://fixtradingcommunity.org, and then go to this page to download the specs in PDF format:

> http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/pg/structure/tech-specs/fix-protocol

The specs will tell you exactly what `bodyLength` and `checkSum` are and how they are computed.  Luckily, QuickFIX does these computations for you.

Purposes of those fields:

- bodylength: tells the receiving parser how many bytes the message should be.  If the parser finds it has less bytes than that, then there was a problem in either the sender or receiver.
- checksum: again, helps the receiver detect a problem.  If the receiver's computed checksum doesn't match field 10, then someone's got a bug.

Comment: Can you give me the direct link to download the pdf? That link above is ambiguous.

Comment: And my question is "what is purpose of those in FixMessage"?

Comment: It's not ambiguous.  You have to create an account and login, then the links to pdfs will appear on that page.

Comment: I added the purposes of those fields to this answer.

Comment: this link returns 502, i think the correct one is: https://www.inforeachinc.com/fix-dictionary/index.html where you can choose the protocol version and search for the needed field

Answer (score 3):

from https://fiximate.fixtrading.org/ which is on the FIX protocol's official website:

> 9 |BodyLength |   Length | Message length, in bytes, forward to the
> CheckSum field. ALWAYS SECOND FIELD IN MESSAGE. (Always unencrypted) | Added  FIX.2.7
>
> 10 |   CheckSum |  String | Three byte, simple checksum (see
> Volume 2: "Checksum Calculation" for description). ALWAYS LAST FIELD
> IN MESSAGE; i.e. serves, with the trailing , as the
> end-of-message delimiter. Always defined as three characters. (Always
> unencrypted) | Added  FIX.2.7

Comment: What is purpose of those in Message? How to calculate?

Comment: this link returns 502, i think the correct one is: https://www.inforeachinc.com/fix-dictionary/index.html where you can choose the protocol version and search for the needed field

Comment: @user666 actually https://fiximate.fixtrading.org/legacy/index.html is the correct link, I'm updating it now